# Vue Kendo Scheduler How to implement Drop event from external source: ie list

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, scheduler

I want to allow users to drag and drop template to create events in scheduler. But i cant find a drop event. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: here is the sample project.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H1pewI1zufrNca1pVVWgFH2S_5ErkZYk?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to create event on drop action of right side list items.